# On-the-fly compression of stdin failing?

Tags: sql-server, command-line, compression, gzip, 7zip

From what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798567/is-there-a-way-to-directly-compres-zips-the-result-from-a-sql-query), I am trying to pipe the output from `sqlcmd` to `7zip` so that I can save disk space when dumping a 200GB database. I have tried the following:

```
> sqlcmd -S <DBNAME> -Q "SELECT * FROM ..." | .\7za.exe a -si <FILENAME>
```

This does not seem to be working even when I leave the system for a whole day. However, the following works:

```
> sqlcmd -S <DBNAME> -Q "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM ..." | .\7za.exe a -si <FILENAME>
```

and even this one:

```
> sqlcmd -S <DBNAME> -Q "SELECT * FROM ..."
```

When I remove the `pipe` symbol, I can see the results and can even redirect it to a file within finishes in 7 hours.

I am not sure what is going on with piping large amount of output but what I could understand up until this point is that 7zip seems to be waiting to consume the whole input before it creates an archive file (because I don't really see a file being created to begin with) so I am not sure if it is actually performing on-the-fly compression. So I tried gzip and here's my experience:

```
> echo "Test" | .\gzip.exe > test.gz
> .\gzip.exe test.gz
gzip: test.gz: not in gzip format
```

I am not sure I am doing this the right way. Any suggestions?

Comment: double-post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798567/is-there-a-way-to-directly-compres-zips-the-result-from-a-sql-query

Comment: I don't think so. The first one was whether it was possible to do it using SQL Server and this one is more about how to perform on-the-fly compression. 7zip, that was suggested in the other post, is indeed the right answer but just not for my case and am seeking an alternate way of doing it. The input to 7zip or gzip does not have to be SQLCMD output. Even `echo` is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy! It was PowerShell all along! I have no idea why this is happening at least with gzip. Gzip kept complaining that the input was not in gzip format. I switched over to the normal command prompt and everything started working.

I did observe this before. Looks like `|` and `>` have a slightly different functionality in PowerShell and Command prompt. Not sure what exactly it is but if someone knows about it, please add in here.